# How to handle spaces in path of log file?

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to solve this bug report: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19447

Jenkins is invoking the following command-line:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_\jdk.exe" /s /v /qn /L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_\jdk.exe.install.log" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_"`

It turns out that msiexec doesn't like the path of the log (the /L parameter). If the log resides in a path with spaces, msiexec complains that the command-line is invalid. If the log path does not contain spaces, it works fine. I'm guessing that the quotes are being ignored and the path is being parsed as two separate parameters.

**How do I get msiexec to accept paths with spaces?**

Comment: You can avoid the spaces by using 8.3 names if the system has them enabled.

Comment: @Gabe, comments are not answers :) Please post a formal answer.

Comment: Avoiding isn't handling, so I just left a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got lucky (through trial and error and the power of Google):

The trick is to surround `/V`'s argument with quotes, and escape the nested quotes using `\"`. Here is the updated command-line.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_\jdk.exe" /s /v"/qn /L \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_\jdk.exe.install.log\" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_auto-install_\""`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jdk.exe but the /s /v /qn indicates it's an InstallShield setup.exe.  Typically this would be foo.exe /s /v"" where s and v are switches to the IS Setup.exe and everything following the /v are args to be passed into the child msiexec process.  These things then need to be double escaped.